# parse() missing 1 required positional argument: 'stream'

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views

Currently, I want to render the data using a REST API in django and I got the following error:

`parse() missing 1 required positional argument: 'stream'`.

Any solutions?

```
@csrf_exempt
def article_key_list(request,pk):
    try:
        article = Article.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except Article.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse(status=404)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        serial = Article_serializer(article)
        return JsonResponse(serial.data)

    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        data = JSONParser.parse(request)
        serial = Article_serializer(data=data)
        if serial.is_valid():
            serial.save()
            return JsonResponse(serial.data,status=201)
        return JsonResponse(serial.errors,status=404)

    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        article.delete()
        return HttpResponse(status=204)
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Comment: See documentation of parser at https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/: "To implement a custom parser, you should override BaseParser, set the .media_type property, and implement the .parse(self, stream, media_type, parser_context) method. The method should return the data that will be used to populate the request.data property. The arguments passed to .parse() are: ..."

Answer (score 10):

You should write:

```
JSONParser().parse(request)
```

Instead of:

```
JSONParser.parse(request)
```

Comment: Life saver! Give this man a bells!